# Use button to change screens

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making a simple bank system and I've been having trouble with **creating a button that changes the screen** and It would change the screen as button is pressed. I have tried using code such as `screen = 1;` in the problem but it doesnt seem to work

```js
    let sumbit;
let input;
    let fullScreen;
let element, sizeback;
    let clear;
let check = 2;
let mainScreen;
let screen = 0;


//if(!alert('Alert For your User!')){window.location.reload();}

function begining() {
  createCanvas(1000, 500);
background(100,250);
//sizeback = background(100,200,250);
      sumbit = createButton('Submit');
  sumbit.mousePressed(button);
      sumbit.position(190, 60);

  input = createInput();
      input.position(20, 60);

  element = createElement('h2', 'What is the password : ');
      element.position(5, 10);

  fullScreen = createButton('FullScreen');
  fullScreen.mousePressed(full);
  fullscreen.noLoop()


  textAlign(CENTER);
      textSize(32);
}

function draw() {
  if(screen == 0) {
    begining()
  } else if(screen == 1) {
    bankScreen()
  } else if(screen == 2) {
    logout()
  }
}
//FullScreen button
function full() {
    let fs = fullscreen();
      fullscreen(!fs);
}

//Submit button 
function button() {
  const password = input.value();
  if(password == 2021) {
        element.html('Your Correct! ' + ' The answer was ' + password);
    for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      push();
        fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
        translate(random(height), random(width));
            rotate(random(2 * PI));
        text(password, 20, 20);
      pop();
      let next = createButton('Next');
      next.mousePressed(nextpage);
      next.noLoop();
    }
    screen = 1;
  } else {
    if(!alert('Would you like to try again ?')){window.location.reload();}
  }  
 input.value('');
}

function bankScreen() {
  background(100,200,250);
  text("Login", 10, 50);
  
}

function nextpage() {
  screen = 1;
//Problem!!
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please be specific about what your "trouble" is.

Comment: @user1599011 My trouble is that after getting the password right and clicking next it should switch over to ```function bankscreen()``` but it does not.

Comment: from `draw()`? What's the value of `screen` when `draw()` is called?

Comment: The value of ```screen``` in ```draw()``` is when the value of ```screen``` changes the screen changes. Originally I used the ```mousePressed()``` function but It doesn't fit the button.

Comment: But what's the actual value of `screen` at runtime?

Comment: If you make your code a runnable snippet and are more specific about what the expected/desired behavior is it will be a lot easier for people to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410651/how-do-i-include-a-runnable-p5-js-sketch-in-a-stackoverflow-question

Comment: @user1599011 the value of ```screen``` starts at 0

Comment: But what is the value of `screen` when when `draw()` is run?

Comment: @user1599011 The value changes depending on screen

Comment: Yep. And that's where `bankscreen()` would be called, but you said it's not getting called, so check the value of `screen` in `draw()`

Comment: The value of ```screen``` is ```0``` and It is getting increased to ```1``` when calling ```bankscreen()``` but it doesnt seem to be calling the ```bankscreen()```. Perhaps the ```screen``` value isn't changing.

Comment: Exactly. Need to determine if that's true and why.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the ```nextpage()``` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous issues with the posted code, and it is hard to tell which are because this code is incomplete, and which are bugs. However here are a few issues that stand out.

- You have no `setup` function
- You are creating a new canvas on every call to `begining` which doesn't make much sense.
- You are creating HTML elements in functions called in `draw`

  - Unless you disable looping you should not do this because HTML elements are persistent.
- You are calling `noLoop` as an instance method on `p5.Element` in multiple places, this is not valid.
- In the button function you create 200 "Next" buttons, that's probably not what you want to do.
- In the `button` function you do a bunch of drawing, but unless looping is disabled this will immediately be covered up by the call to `background` in `bankScreen` on the next execution of `draw`
- You don't remove the elements from the "beginning" screen when the submit button is clicked and you try to move to the "bankScreen"
- When next page is clicked you are already on screen = 1 so that function has no effect.

I've attempted to fix the issues with your code:

```js
let sumbit;
let input;
let fullScreen;
let element, sizeback;
let clear;
let check = 2;
let mainScreen;
let screen = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noLoop();
}

function begining() {
  background(100, 250);
  //sizeback = background(100,200,250);
  sumbit = createButton('Submit');
  sumbit.mousePressed(button);
  sumbit.position(190, 60);

  input = createInput();
  input.position(20, 60);

  element = createElement('h2', 'What is the password : ');
  element.position(5, 10);

  fullScreen = createButton('FullScreen');
  fullScreen.mousePressed(full);
  // ???? This isn't a function on p5.Element
  // fullscreen.noLoop()


  textAlign(LEFT);
  textSize(32);
}

function draw() {
  if (screen == 0) {
    begining()
  } else if (screen == 1) {
    bankScreen()
  } else if (screen == 2) {
    logout()
  }
}

//FullScreen button
function full() {
  let fs = fullscreen();
  fullscreen(!fs);
}

//Submit button 
function button() {
  const password = input.value();
  if (password == 2021) {
    element.html('Your Correct! ' + ' The answer was ' + password);
    sumbit.remove();
    input.remove();
    // All of this drawing is pointless because it will be overridden in bankScreen();
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      push();
      fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
      translate(random(height), random(width));
      rotate(random(2 * PI));
      text(password, 20, 20);
      pop();
      // Why are you making 200 Next buttons?
      let next = createButton('Next');
      // Don't forget to position your buttons
      next.position(width / 2, height / 2);
      next.mousePressed(nextpage);
      // ????? noLoop isn't a method on p5.Element
      // next.noLoop();
    }
    screen = 1;
    // Need to redraw since we disabled looping
    redraw();
  } else {
    if (!alert('Would you like to try again ?')) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  }
  input.value('');
}

function bankScreen() {
  background(100, 200, 250);
  text("Login", 10, 150);
}

function nextpage() {
  // This does nothing because when it runs screen is already equal to 1 
  screen = 1;
  // Need to redraw since we disabled looping
  redraw();
  // What Problem?
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```