# In p5.js how do I create a moving animation of an array group of lines?

Tags: html, css, p5.js

Hi I created a sparkler like shape in P5.js using `array()` and `randomGaussian()`. Here is what it looks like with the codes in p5.js:

[image: screenshot of generated drawing]

```js
let distribution = new Array(360);
let b = false;
let x, y;

function setup() {
  var cny = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  cnv.parent("sketchholder");
  for (let i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
    distribution[i] = floor(randomGaussian(60, 50));
  }

  colorMode(HSB, 255);
  // hue, saturation, brightness
  x = width / 4;
  у = height / 3;
}

function draw() {
  background(21, 30, 10);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);

  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(255, 70);
  line(0, 0, -x, y);
  if (b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
      rotate(TWO_PI / distribution.length);
      var colorH = random(0, 255);
      var colorS = random(100, 200);
      var colorB = random(0, 255);
      var YY = random(1, 4);
      stroke(colorH, colorS, colorB);
      strokeWeight(YY);
      strokeCap(ROUND);
      let dist = abs(distribution[i]);
      line(0, 0, dist, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

And I would like it to move slowly along the stick and disappear after like 20s before reaching the end. Can I achieve that in p5.js? Or can I create the same effect using the p5.js layer as a div in html and animate it in CSS?
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Instead include the code with proper formatting (see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189). Preferably post your code as a [runnable StackSnippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67410652/229247).

Comment: @Dietrich you are a saint for that edit! Somebody else please approve the pending edit, it needs one more approval.

Comment: @PaulWheeler I'm glad I could help! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do this with p5.js. I think it would not make much sense to try to do an animation like this with CSS and that wouldn't work well with p5.js regardless (you would only be able to animate DOM elements). However, you do need to basically implement your own animation system with different parameter values for different times in the animation and then interpolating between them yourself. Here is a basic example:

```js
let distribution = new Array(360);

let originX, originY;

let keyframes = [];
let keyframeTimes = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  for (let i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
    distribution[i] = floor(randomGaussian(60, 50));
  }

  colorMode(HSB, 255);
  // hue, saturation, brightness
  
  // Origin relative to the center of the sketch
  originX = -width / 4;
  originY = height / 3;
  const lenX = width / 4;
  const lenY = - height / 3;
  // Add the desired parameters and times to keyframes and keyframeTimes
  keyframes.push({
    x: lenX,
    y: lenY,
    mag: 1
  });
  keyframeTimes.push(0);
  
  keyframes.push({
    x: 0.2 * lenX,
    y: 0.2 * lenY,
    mag: 0
  });
  keyframeTimes.push(20);
}

function draw() {
  background(21, 30, 10);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  translate(originX, originY);

  strokeWeight(3);
  stroke(255, 70);
  
  // Find the next keyframe that we are animating towards.
  let nextKeyframeIx = keyframeTimes.findIndex(t => t > millis() / 1000);
  // Find the current/previous keyframe that we are starting from.
  // Cases to consider: the next keyframe is the first one in the list, we're in
  // between two keyframes, or there is no next keyframe
  let keyframeIx =
      nextKeyframeIx === 0 ?
        // There is no previous keyframe (we're at the beginning)
        0 :
        // If we're beyond the end of the list, just use the parameters from the
        // last keyframe
        (nextKeyframeIx > 0 ? nextKeyframeIx - 1 : keyframes.length - 1);
  
  let x, y, mag;
  
  if (keyframeIx < nextKeyframeIx) {
    // lerp between the current and next keyframe
    let kf1 = keyframes[keyframeIx];
    let kf2 = keyframes[nextKeyframeIx];
    let t1 = keyframeTimes[keyframeIx];
    let t2 = keyframeTimes[nextKeyframeIx];
    let amt = (millis() / 1000 - t1) / (t2 - t1);
    x = lerp(kf1.x, kf2.x, amt);
    y = lerp(kf1.y, kf2.y, amt);
    mag = lerp(kf1.mag, kf2.mag, amt);
  } else {
    // just use the current/previous keyframe
    let kf = keyframes[keyframeIx];
    x = kf.x;
    y = kf.y;
    mag = kf.mag;
  }
  
  // Draw a line from the origin (bottom left of the sparkler) to the current
  // x,y position of the end of the sparkler
  line(0, 0, x, y);
  // Translate to the current end of the sparkler for drawing the colored lines
  translate(x, y);
  if (mag > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < distribution.length; i++) {
      rotate(TWO_PI / distribution.length);
      const colorH = random(0, 255);
      const colorS = random(100, 200);
      const colorB = random(0, 255);
      const YY = random(1, 4);
      stroke(colorH, colorS, colorB);
      strokeWeight(YY);
      strokeCap(ROUND);
      let dist = abs(distribution[i]) * mag;
      line(0, 0, dist, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```