# My p5.js code is sometimes lagging and idont know how?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, p5.js

I am a beginner to p5.js and I was trying to make a catching game, where the balls fall from the sky and you catch them with a basket, but when you run the code, sometimes the balls don't fall down until waiting a few seconds and moving the basket around, could anyone tell me why this is?

Here is my code:

```
let speed = 3;
let x = 300;
let y = 0;
let score = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  y = y + speed;
  rect(mouseX, height - 10, 60, 40);
  fill(255);
  text("score = " + score, 30, 20);

  if (y > height - 10 && x > mouseX - 20 && x < mouseX + 20) {
    y = -20;
    speed += 1;
    score += 1;
  }
  if (y == -20) {
    x = random(width);
  }
}
function reset(){
  score = 0;
  speed = 2;
  y = -20;
}
```

Comment: When asking questions on StackOverflow you should include you code, preferably as a [Runnable Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67410652/229247) rather than linking to an external site.

Answer (score 2):

Your game logic seems a bit strange:

Each frame you increase `y` by speed. Each frame you check if the `y` value has passed paddle position (`height - 10`) and is in is within the the area of the paddle (although the math for this is a little off). However, you don't have any condition for when the ball has gone off the edge of the screen and missed the paddle. As a result nothing happens once the ball goes off screen until the player moves the paddle to a position where it would have caught the ball.

Here's a fixed version:

```js
let speed = 2;
let x = 300;
let y = 0;
let score = 0;
let coolDown = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  x = width / 2;
}

function draw() {
  if (coolDown > 0) {
    background('red');
  } else {
    background(0);
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
    y = y + speed;
  }
  rect(mouseX - 20, height - 10, 40, 10);
  fill(255);
  text("score = " + score, 30, 20);
  // After the player misses give them a second
  if (coolDown > 0) {
    coolDown--;
    return;
  }
  if (y > height - 10 && x > mouseX - 20 && x < mouseX + 20) {
    y = -20;
    speed += 0.5;
    score += 1;
  } else if (y > height) {
    // The ball is off screen
    coolDown = 30;
    y = -20;
    score -= 1;
  }
  if (y == -20) {
    x = random(width);
  }
}
function reset() {
  score = 0;
  speed = 2;
  y = -20;
}
```

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

One other thing to be aware of is that if you move your mouse outside of the window or iframe then p5.js will not update the `mouseX` and `mouseY` positions. To prevent this from happening you can look into using [requestPointerLock](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/requestPointerLock).