# text not displaying in constructor

Tags: constructor, p5.js

Code and output is listed in image. The text doesn't show up. Funny thing is, this worked in previous versions, but not in the newest version. I'm trying to get the title to the top left corner and the description to the bottom. trycatch says there's no error. The text displayed when I removed the last 2 parameters of the text function, but the text ended up all over the place. [Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaiEN.png).

Code is listed below

```
var thing

class Item {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, name, desc) {
    let tc = color(1, 1, 1)
    let size = windowWidth / 95
    tc.setAlpha(0)

    fill(tc)
    rectMode(CENTER)
    textSize(size)
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.width = width
    this.height = height
    this.name = name
   
    this.desc = desc
    this.name = name
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)

    fill(0)
    textAlign(LEFT)
    
    text(this.name, this.x + (windowWidth / 95 / 2), this.y + (windowWidth / 95 / 2), this.width / 2, this.height / 2)
  
    textAlign(CENTER)
    text(this.desc, this.x, this.y + this.width / 4, this.width, this.height / 3)
  }
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
}
function draw(){
      thing = new Item((windowWidth / 3) / 4, windowWidth / 7, windowWidth / 6.7, windowWidth / 7, 'samplename', 'sampledesc')

}
```

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) --- [How do I include a runnable p5.js sketch in a StackOverflow question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67410651/how-do-i-include-a-runnable-p5-js-sketch-in-a-stackoverflow-question)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `rectMode(CENTER)` is cutting off your text.

```
var thing

class Item {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, name, desc) {
    let size = windowWidth / 95

        //noFill() sets the fill to transparent
        noFill()

    textSize(size)
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.width = width
    this.height = height
    this.name = name
    this.desc = desc

    rect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)

    fill(0)
        
    textAlign(LEFT)
    text(this.name, this.x + (windowWidth / 95 / 2), this.y + (windowWidth / 95 / 2), this.width, this.height)
        
    textAlign(CENTER)
    text(this.desc, this.x, this.y + this.width / 4, this.width, this.height / 3)
  }
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight)
    //create a new test Item
    thing = new Item(width/2, height/2, 200, 200, "test name", "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
}
```